# Present View Controller as Modal View in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I was searching here and I couldn't find the right answer. I'm using storyboards. Project is in iOS 6 and above. I have a root view in which I load some data from one service. I'm not connecting anything inside storyboard because I need to choose in program when to show certain View. In this case I need to show modal view or popup view when user is launching the app for the first time. User opens an app, I then check if the user is registered, if not, show my modal view with language view picker. I'm doing everything in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method. 
This is my implementation in viewDidAppear:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *firstTimeOpenedApp = [defaults objectForKey:FirstTimeOpenedApp];
if (firstTimeOpenedApp == nil)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(presentLanguageViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

My selector:

```
- (void)presentLanguageViewController
{
  LanguageViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:LangaugeViewControllerIdentifier];
  viewController.languageViewModel = [LanguageViewModel new];
  [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is that it shows always for a second and after that the screen is black. I know it has something to do that only one view controller can be ''opened'', but how to retain it. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Do you actually have storyboard ID at your LanguageViewController?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have just put it as const string. It is called the same: LangaugeViewControllerIdentifier

Comment: Add a breakpoint on this line: `viewController.languageViewModel = [LanguageViewModel new];` and see if viewController is correctly instantiated by the line above.

Comment: Are you presenting this model view controller from the rootViewController?

Comment: Everything seems ok. The same behaviour of explained problem was even before I've added viewModel for this view.

Comment: @NitheeshGeorge yes, I need to have modal view controller on my rootView controller. root view is actually like a splash screen in which I load some data from service.

Comment: Try to create new view controller in storyboard and set another storyboard id. And then try to present modally that new controller. Maybe some issue with `LanguageViewController` itself?

Comment: And is it a good idea to present the controller from viewDidAppear. because the viewDidApper can be invoked each when the viewController is visible to the user

Comment: are you getting the same issue when presenting from viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes the sam thing in load method. i put it in didappear beacuse i thought that views will be all loaded by then. Controller only has some components on it and nothing binded so it is ok. It is ViewController, i am not using navigation controller here on anything different.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so the problem must be elsewhere.  Is there any other code in the root view controller that mentions the LanguageViewController? Try implementing dealloc in the LanguageViewController class, and put a log in it to see if it's called.

Comment: There is no mention of LanguageViewController anywhere but in this code that i have posted. When I do not have delay in selector, it immediatly goes black.

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong. I guess,the view controller background color is black. Try changing it to white and see if it works

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help :) It is working now when I've set background colour to white. Background colour was set to clear. I want to show that initial view controller in background. Anybody knows why it is not working when colour is set to clear?